# WPF - Changing Focus from a RichTextBox causes a InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

Running into a strange issue when I have to switch focus from a RichTextBox. The xaml for my application is as follows:

```
<Window Name="MyWindow" x:Class="WpfBasics.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfBasics"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="400">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>Box 1:</TextBlock>
        <RichTextBox x:Name="Box1" TextChanged="Box1_TextChanged" />
        <TextBlock>Box 2:</TextBlock>
        <RichTextBox x:Name="Box2" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

With the following codebehind (only the relevant bit):

```
private void Box1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Box2.Focus();
}
```

The moment I use `Box1`, `Focus` throws the following exception:
    System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot Reopen undo unit while another unit is already open.'

Looking into the CallStack I believe the issue is caused by the `LostFocus` event handler on a `RichTextBox`.

Comment: Seems odd that you'd want to change the focus upon immediately typing in a textbox...

Comment: The example is pretty contrived for the sake of keeping it simple. My use-case is for a form where focus should change after a valid value has been entered

Comment: ah, I see. then the workaround I mentioned could work. call your ChangeFocus method in `TextChanged` event if a valid value is entered.

Comment: Just tried it, and the issues remains. When I look at the callstack, it's calls to `Undo` and `_FlushPendingInputItems(TextEditor This)` that causes the issue. My best guess so far is that RichTextBoxes share some kind of shared queue that is being accessed at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you gave, I created a sample project that seems to work. Give this a shot:

```
private void Box1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RichTextBox textBox = sender as RichTextBox;
    var text = new TextRange(textBox.Document.ContentStart, textbox.Document.ContentEnd).Text;

    if (IsValid(text))
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)ChangeFocus);
    }
}

private void ChangeFocus()
{
    Box2.Focus();
}

private bool IsValid(string text)
{
    var plainText = text.Substring(0, text.Length - 2);

    if (plainText == "hello world")
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly for my case. Do you have any insight on why dispatching the change focus seems to avoid the issue? - Or why this is not a problem with a regular `TextBox`?